# AttributeError while reading string form google cloud storage in python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have very simple function that reads a google cloud storage text file.

```
def readFileFromBucket(filename):
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('<mybucket>')
    blob = bucket.get_blob(filename)
    return blob.download_as_string()
```

This seems to work for other people. But in my case I am getting:

```
> /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.pyc
> in _write_to_stream(self, response)
>     115         else:
>     116             md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
> --> 117         with response:
>     118             # NOTE: This might "donate" ``md5_hash`` to the decoder and replace
>     119             #       it with a ``_DoNothingHash``.
> 
> AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: This does not seem like a proper traceback, can you double check and put the whole traceback, properly formatted? Normally the error would say the attribute name etc, here it seems to complain about md5!

Comment: Sounds like this this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3747). Please share version of libraries you are were using.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and i have not idea how to fix it.
Anyway, here a workaround:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

with file_io.FileIO("gs://<BUCKET>/file.txt", "rb") as f:
  text = f.readlines()
```